404 error page not displaying due to validations toastr error code in my script
I am working on a php project with laravel  where i used errors->any() to capture all errors and display them with toastr lib within my script.
The issue now is that when I implemented a 404 error page, the toastr is not able to catch the error and hence the website breaks.
Please what could i do so that the toastr lib displays errors only when the error is coming from validations and notifications and not when the error is due to 404 page not found?
See below the the codes in the exceptions -> handler.php ,  that displays the 404 pages. ( I actually have two 404 pages, one for admin and the other for the website).
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * The list of the inputs that are never flashed to the session on validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }


public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        // Check if the URL starts with '/admin' to differentiate between the areas
        if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
            // Return the custom admin 404 view
            return response()->view('errors.404-admin', [], 404);
        }

        // Return the custom website 404 view for all other pages
        return response()->view('errors.404-website', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

This is the code in my script

<script>
    @if($errors->any())
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error )
        toastr.error('{{$error}}');
      @endforeach
    @endif
  </script>
  <script>

When I comment out the error/toastr code in the script, the 404 error pages were able to display very well. But I was not able to get validation errors displayed from my pages.
Error i get when I try to display the 404 page with the toastr code in the script

According to the Laravel documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors, "An $errors variable is shared with all of your application's views by the Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware, which is provided by the web middleware group. When this middleware is applied an $errors variable will always be available in your views, allowing you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used.

You can pass the
$is404 = true;

like
return response()->view('errors.404-admin', ['is404' => $is404], 404);

on return response to the blade view
and check it in the script
<script>
    @if(isset($is404) && $is404)
        // do nothing
    @else
        @if($errors->any())
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error )
                toastr.error('{{$error}}');
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endif
</script>

other than you can try this also
<script>
    @if(!empty($errors) && $errors->any())
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            toastr.error('{{ $error }}');
        @endforeach
    @endif
</script>


(1) why define a variable with a static value, only to use it immediately after? Just use 'is404' => true], no? (2) Next time, please use proper/consistent indentation. This is like, the absolute very basic thing and programmer should do.  (3) I don't understand why you have to make an empty if-block. Just invert the condition.. and secondly you can also merge the two if statements into one: @if((!isset($is404) || $is404) && $errors->any())

Thanks for this response. The second option with @if(!empty($errors) && $errors=>any()) works well.
The first option will require me to declare  $is404 variable in all my controller functions and even though i may have to set them to false. Because when i tried the 1st option while the page i want to visit exists, i got a new error saying that $is404 is not defined.
But the 2nd option works fine. Thanks a lot
